# objectForKey null check

Tags: ios, objective-c

Trying to check for validity of the data in item 
(item is `NSDictionary`)

I thought this should work but I do get into the second if and crash with:
`unrecognized selector sent to instance`
becuase `galleryArr` is `(null)`

```
    NSArray *galleryArr = [item objectForKey:@"photos"];

    if (galleryArr != nil ) {
        if ([galleryArr count] != 0) {
            //do something
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: gallerArr is not null .. you would have got something like `[__dataType count]` unrecognized selector... in short the `galleryArr` is declared NSArray.. but in actual it isnt

Comment: Is this from a JSON object? Because you might be getting the instance of `NSNull` which isn't equal to `nil`

Comment: It is from JSON object, I tried 
if (galleryArr != [NSNull null] ) {
Didn't work as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a check for `[gallryArr isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]`.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this issue with a simple this simple Objective-C category:

NSDictionary+NotNull.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

/*! This category extends NSDictionary to work around an issue with NSNull object.
 */
@interface NSDictionary (NotNull)

/*! @abstract Returns the value associated with a given key, but only if the value is not NSNull.
    @param aKey The key for which to return the corresponding value.
    @return The value associated with the given key, or nil if no value is associated with the key, or the value is NSNull.
 */
- (id)objectOrNilForKey:(id)aKey;

@end
```

NSDictionary+NotNull.m

```
#import "NSDictionary+NotNull.h"

@implementation NSDictionary (NotNull)

- (id)objectOrNilForKey:(id)aKey
{
    id object = [self objectForKey:aKey];
    if (object == [NSNull null]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return object;
}

@end
```

Now you can just call:

```
NSArray *galleryArr = [item objectOrNilForKey:@"photos"];
```

Comment: I just had this idea and scrolled down - and here it was!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you get `NSNull`? That's a singleton (`[NSNull null]`) object that represent nil. You can check `if([gallryArr isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])`.