# How to check if NSDictionary key is NULL

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to check if an object exist for the key `next_max_id` in my JSON response dictionary.
I've tried the following ways to check:

- `if ([[pagination objectForKey:@"next_max_id"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) ...`
- `if ([pagination objectForKey:@"next_max_id"] == [NSNull class]) ...`
- `if ([pagination objectForKey:@"next_max_id"]) ...`

However, when the pagination dictionary is empty i.e. (`pagination = {};`), I get these error messages:

```
-[NSNull objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...
```

How else can I check for if the object or rather the key exist, without a crash?

Updated:
When the key `next_max_id` exist inside `pagination`, the JSON response would be like this

```
"pagination": {
    "next_url": "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/puppy/media/recent?access_token=fb2e77d.47a0479900504cb3ab4a1f626d174d2d&max_id=13872296",
    "next_max_id": "13872296"
}
```

Comment: Is the key next_max_id  is available if object is null for key next_max_id in the dictionary

Comment: `next_max_id` does not exist if there is no value. JSON response would be like this `pagination = {};`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the error that you describe, pagination is not an NSDictionary, but pagination itself is an NSNull object. So the first check before everything else would be

```
if (pagination == [NSNull null]) ...
```

That wouldn't happen if your JSON data contains "pagination": {} but it would happen if your JSON data contains "pagination": null .

Answer (score 6):

```
if( [pagination objectForKey:@"your_key"] == nil ||  
    [[pagination objectForKey:@"your_key"] isEqual:[NSNull null]] ){
    //nil dictionary
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check it this way

```
[pagination objectForKey:@"next_max_id"] == [NSNull null]
```

if this won't work try

```
[pagination objectForKey:@"next_max_id"] == (id)[NSNull null]
```

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem is the fact that `pagination` is `nil`, you can't really call any selectors over `NSNull`. As you've mentioned - the problem only occurs when the `pagination` JSON is empty - thus you get a nil object.

so,

```
if (pagination && ![pagination isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
    ... // Do your things
}
```

if pagination is a valid `NSDictionary` object, `objectForKey:` for an inexistent key will return `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

To check the key exists nor not:

```
if([pagination objectForKey:@"next_max_id"] != nil) {
   // exists
}
else {
   // not exists
}
```

To check the key exists and the value is `null`

```
if([pagination objectForKey:@"next_max_id"] == [NSNull null]) {
   // {"next_max_id":null, ...}
}
else {
   // not exists or values is not null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example i have created this demo you can modify according you

```
NSDictionary *pagination = 
[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
   @"https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/puppy/media/recent?access_token=fb2e77d.47a0479900504cb3ab4a1f626d174d2d&max_id=13872296",@"next_url",
   @"65765343",@"next_max_id",   nil];

NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[pagination allKeys]];

if ( [array containsObject:@"next_max_id"] ) {
    NSLog( @"%@",[pagination valueForKey:@"next_max_id"] );
} else {
    NSLog(@"Key is null");
}
```

Comment: there should be a for loop. something like bellow.
for (int i = 0; i<pagination.count; i++)
    {
        if ([array containsObject:@"next_max_id"])
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",[pagination valueForKey:@"next_max_id"]);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Key is null");
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
if( [pagination objectForKey:@"next_max_id"] == nil ||  
    [[pagination objectForKey:@"next_max_id"] isEqual:[NSNull null]] ||
    [pagination objectForKey:@"next_max_id"] == [NSNull null])
{
    NSLog(@"Key is null");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[pagination valueForKey:@"next_max_id"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A very elegant solution is to write a quick Category for the NSDictionary.

For example:

```
#import "NSDictionary+safe.h"

@implementation NSDictionary (safeJSON)

- (id)safeObjectForKey:(NSString *)key {

    id object = [self objectForKey:key];
    if (object == [NSNull null]) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        return object;
    }
}

@end
```

This was also mentioned by rckoenes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22640015/1374488).

Answer (score 0):

> -[NSNull objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

#### The error is In your hands already.

When you calling `[pagination objectForKey:]`, it calls `-[NSNull objectForKey:]`

Means, `pagination` is `NSNull` **NOT** `NSDictionary`. **NSNull** doesn't have `objectForKey:` method to call. That's why you got error:

> unrecognized selector sent to instance

You can check this by,

```
if ([pagination isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    id value =[pagination objectForKey:@"key"];
}
```